# WAMP: How to fix “Firefox is already running” error

Tags: windows-7, firefox, wamp

I am running WAMP server and Windows-7.

This seems to be a Windows-7 specific issue, because this did not happen in either Vista or XP. Whenever I have Firefox already running (such as from a shortcut) and then I try and open the phpMyAdmin link from the taskbar menu, I get a “Firefox is already running” error.

My only solution is to close all of my FireFox windows, (which is a pain since I will only have to re-open them.) and then use the taskbar shortcut.

It seems not to happen if it is the *first* window I open.

I would love to not have to do this everytime. Is there a registry patch that can split separate FireFox instances into separate processes?

Comment: You are running the most recent version right?

Comment: Newest versions of everything...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using [Portable Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable/).
If not, is the PHPMyAdmin link a simple .url hyperlink? (I don't think so)
If it is, then iI recommend you make another Firefox shortcut and in the arguments, add the PHPMyAdmin panel link.
Lastly, I recommend [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) over WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Windows 7 UAC control. Go to the Firefox installation directory and right click the Firefox.exe application file and open the properties. On the compatibility tab at the bottom, enable the program to run as administrator.

If the UAC pop ups each time you start Firefox asking for permission then you would need to follow similar instructions shown [on this Super User page](https://superuser.com/questions/440544/how-to-start-wampserver-without-providing-administrator-privileges) for wampserver.

Note that this leaves you with a shortcut icon, so you can then change the icon properties of that icon back to the Firefox one!