# How to start WampServer without providing administrator privileges?

Tags: administrator, uac

I just set up Dexpot to start WampServer automatically when I enter a new desktop. The problem is that I've hidden my taskbar, and WampServer needs administrative rights. So I have to use Alt-Tab to get to the "Give admin rights" box, and accept it. This is not as automatically as I want. Is it possible to give WampServer admin rights every time automatically?

Comment: Why not run WAMP server as Service??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open Run (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and type `taskschd.msc`. Now click create task. You'll see a window like this. Give your task a name, and select the option named `Run with highest privileges`. You may also give the task a description and/or change the user (Though if the user doesn't have administrator rights, you'll run into issues).

[image: Create task window]

When you're done giving it a name and setting `Run with highest privileges`, go to the actions tab and hit the `New` button. You will now see a window like this, click `Browse` and find the location of your WAMP server application and click ok. Add any arguments if you need.

[image: Create an action]

You can now run this application from Task Scheduler however it makes it easier to have a shortcut.

Navigate to your desktop or a folder where you want a shortcut to launch WAMP and right-click, then click new then click shortcut. Now, when it says `What item would you like to create a shortcut for?` type in the bar `schtasks /run /tn “taskname”`. Replace `taskname` with the name you gave the task you created.

You can now run the shortcut you created and you won't get any UAC dialogues.

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry for waking up this old thread, i did those steps, and everything is working fine, however the tray icon doesn't show up using this method, is it normal? is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @DannyG I wouldn't think so considering it's not ran on your user.

Comment: i didn't quite understand what you mean, can you possibly clarify?

Comment: @DannyG I believe what Adam meant was that because the WAMP GUI was started by the Administrator user you don't see the GUI icon in the taskbar when you're logged in as a different user . I'm still looking for a way around this. (this comment is for posterity as this question is highly ranked on Google)

Comment: @NightOwl yeah, it's an old comment too right now, i got it, i have WAMP running an all stations without GUI, haven't found a workaround for this, but tbh haven't tried much either.

Answer (score 0):

use the RunAsTool, it will load the tray for all standard users, Cheers!

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so and **how** to use it.