# Cannot start WampServer without admin privileges

Tags: wamp

I have installed WAMP server in students labs. It is working fine through admin login. But when student login though their account in  Windows 7 , it doesn’t not working. It only works after admin login and I have start the services automatically and also add in startup. But this also could not solve the problem.

I do not want to give admin rights to student group. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Run the service as a task as pointed out by @eramit2010

http://superuser.com/questions/440544/how-to-start-wampserver-without-providing-administrator-privileges

Answer (score 0):

You need admin privilege to run apache and mysql. Normal users cannot run them.